# flat picture (1;16) divide into equal parts (4;4)

Tags: java

I have a Bufferedimage that is 1px high and eg wide. I need to create another Bufferedimage that will be in 1:1 resolution. I know what can be done in this case by calculating the square root of the width, but what if the result is not an integer? I have a method for creating a matrix (a list of each pixel in turn) from the width and height, so there will be no problems. At the end, if there are empty pixels, I can make them transparent, so not necessarily a completely filled square. I just need to get the dimensions of the square, having the width of the original photo, I will fill in the pixels myself.

my code:

```
    public static BufferedImage encode(String str){
        byte[] bytes = str.getBytes();
        BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(bytes.length, 1, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        for (int i = 0; i < bytes.length; i++) {
            img.setRGB(i, 0,encode(bytes[i]).getRGB() );
        }
        return img;
    }
    public static Color encode(byte byt){
        return new Color(byt+128,byt+128,byt+128);
    }
```

Comment: what if the result is not an integer? Well, traditionally you'd round...

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas but if it affects the number of pixels?

Comment: round up on one side, and down on the other. Eg if you have 5.1 and 4.9, they both round to 5; or if you have 5.4 and 5.6, one goes to 5 and the other goes to 6. At the end of the day the sum will remain the same, but you have a round number for each 'chunk'.

Answer (score 0):

```
    public static BufferedImage encode(String str){
        byte[] bytes = str.getBytes();
        int w = bytes.length;
        int width = (int) Math.ceil(Math.sqrt(w));
        BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(width, width, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        for (int index = 0; index < bytes.length; index++) {
            img.setRGB(index%width, (int)Math.floor(index/(float)width),encode(bytes[index]).getRGB() );
        }
        return img;
    }
```

code update. I just calculate the square root, and if the number is not an integer, then I round up to a larger one and as a result I get the height of the image, because the image has a 1:1 format, we immediately got the width. Then I just fill in the formula:

```
x = byteIndex % imageWidth
y = floor(byteIndex / imageHeight)
```